# Android - find animation code

Tags: android, animation

where i can get [this](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B14F_FSUCc01LUJPSVExYmVrTlE/Illustrations_01_ErrorState_v1.webm) this animation code?

I tried but could not find anything. Thank you all for the help

Comment: The dinosaur animation?

Comment: yes, the dinosaur animation

Comment: how you found the animation ?

Comment: In the materiale design Google site

Comment: https://material.google.com/motion/creative-customization.html#creative-customization-illustrations